# WPF - The following type was expected: UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

```
       <ElementHost>
        <dc:MyControl Name="MyControl3"  ShowScrollBars="True" Enabled="true" AutoScroll="True" />
        </ElementHost>
```

My project builds ok, but dc:MyControl is underlined saying:
The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: UIElement

Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: 1) post MyControl . 
2) post ElementHost .
3) post Element . 

Only the signature please , i don't want to see your implementations.

for example : 

  public class Element : AFluffyBunny 
  {
       ... 
  }

Comment: Additionally , I see that ElemenetHost only has a Closing Tag ..

Comment: check that dc:MyControl is actually inheriting from UIElement. Also, double check that the library in which MyControl resides is referenced. Without further info and code listings, there is nothing else to say.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few possible reasons for your error from your code exerpt.

The first is that the `ElementHost` control is actually a Windows Forms control and so shouldn't be used in XAML at all. If you want to host a Windows Forms control in a WPF Application, then you should be using a [`WindowsFormsHost` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. In this case, the `Child` element should be or extend the type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

If however, you are trying to host a WPF element in a Windows Forms Application, then you *should* be using the [`ElementHost` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx), but you should ensure that the `Child` element extends the `UIElement` class as it requires... from the linked page:

> [The `Child` property] Gets or sets the UIElement hosted by the ElementHost control.

You can find out further information from the [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF by Using XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.110).aspx) pages on MSDN.